# How to customise winston output

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I want to make a custom Winston logger output,I'm using winston ^3.2.1, I want to output the logs in both console and a file, here's the out that I would like to get : {timestamp - API_URL - {param1} - {param2} }

here's my code:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = format;
const config = require("./");
const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
});
console.log(myFormat);
const logger = createLogger({
 format: combine(
  label({ label: 'right meow!' }),
  timestamp(),
  myFormat
),
 transports: [new transports.Console(),
   new transports.File({
    filename: logger.log,
    level: 'info'
  })
 ]
 });
module.exports = logger;
```

any help please ?

Comment: You need to put you API_URL and params in the message when you are creating logs (in your code) and this should work!

Comment: or try creating custom formats like: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-custom-formats